# What is the random file in local Git repo with commit information inside?

Tags: c#, git

I'm learning how to use Git with Visual Studio and I just noticed a file that doesn't have an extension in my local repository and I am wondering how it got there in the first place. This is how it shows if I run **git status**:

(Apologies for links, need more reputation to post images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz9GK.jpg

However the file's name in the local repo appears like so in Windows Explorer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXkU6.jpg

I moved the file out of the local Git repo to see if Git or Visual Studio would throw any errors but nothing happened. I am suspecting that this is some sort of log file since when I open it I find the below inside.

**Note that this is only a sample since the file is quite long.**

> [33mcommit 836ebc841dcc16806f4dad33d2ac32b5437b5d32[m[33m ([m[1;36mHEAD -> [m[1;32mmaster[m[33m)[m
> Date:   Mon Aug 12 16:11:23 2019 +0300
>
> Add project files.
>
> [1mdiff --git a/RandomNameGenerator.sln b/RandomNameGenerator.sln[m
> [1mnew file mode 100644[m
>
> [1mindex 0000000..f0bc8d2[m
>
> [1m--- /dev/null[m
>
> [1m+++ b/RandomNameGenerator.sln[m
>
> [36m@@ -0,0 +1,25 @@[m
>
> [32m+[m[32m﻿[m
>
> [32m+[m[32mMicrosoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00[m
>
> [32m+[m[32m# Visual Studio 15[m
>
> [32m+[m[32mVisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28307.645[m
>
> [32m+[m[32mMinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1[m
>
> [32m+[m[32mProject("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") =
> "RandomNameGenerator", "RandomNameGenerator\RandomNameGenerator.csproj", "{18AAEB05-8D77-463F-91DE-ED78FBDE4EB1}"[m

Curiosity has gotten the better of me and I want to know what it is and why it's there?

Much appreciated if anyone can shed some insight.

Comment: It really does look like `git log` output. Maybe your pager is not well behaved and sometimes leaves scratch files behind?

Comment: @torek I assumed as much. I moved the file a few days ago and have been committing to my project on a daily basis. No other similar files have been created since. I'll look into the pager to see if anything is amiss. Thanks for replying :)